# is this possible in angular js : the multiplication of two variable giving zero

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using angular js in PHP .. here is my angular js

```
            <div ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:query | filter:query2"  > 
       <?php
      $first_number = '{{friend.qty}}';
        $second_number = '{{friend.price}}';
        echo $first_number; echo '<br/>';echo $second_number;echo '<br/>';
        $sum_total = $second_number * $first_number;

        print ($sum_total);
```

?>

**The Output is coming as**

```
200
10
0
```

the value stored in `{{friend.qty}}` is displaying as 200 and value stored in `{{friend.price}}` is displaying as 10 
i am not understanding why the output is zero that is `$second_number * $first_number;`

Comment: you cannot use javascipt variables (frontend) in php code (backend)

Comment: but the values of {{friend.qty}} and {{friend.price}} are displaying correctly so why can't sum ..

Comment: because you cannot mix frontend with backend code. Move the calculation to the frontend `{{friend.qty * friend.price}}`.

Comment: Thankyou for quick answer